# How to manage key binding for On-The-Fly Sensitivity adjustment on Razer Synapse 2.0

Tags: razer-mouse

I got the new Razer Deathadder 2013 mouse and installed Razer Synapse 2.0.

Is there a way that I can manage the key binding for On-The-Fly for Razer Synapse 2.0?

I had to bind the On-the-Fly sensitivity to one of my side buttons. Is it possible to add the key bindings to my keyboard which is a non-Razer hardware?

While going through the guide online, there was a section in it that mentioned the following but I couldn't find it.

> Each profile can be set to <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>-<kbd>9</kbd> using 
>   the SHORTCUT dropdown menu for fast  profile switching.

Would appreciate some help on this.